# Как обновить данные в RecyclerView после редактирования его айтема

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть `RecyclerView` в котором есть кнопка редактирования `item`ов. При нажатии на эту кнопку вызывается метод `startActivityForResult` и запускается новое `activity`. После редактирования `item`a вызывается метдод `setResult(RESULT_OK)` и `finish()`. Вопрос как принять результаты в адаптере? Метод `onActivityResult` в нём не работает. Вот здесь пишут [об этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243560/onactivityresult-inside-a-recyclerview-adapter-not-being-used)

Comment: в общем то вам нужно всего лишь в своей активити изменить данные,  которые отображает ваш список (например, записать в БД новые данные, после редактирования). Потом  сделать обновление адаптера (`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`). Не надо здесь никаких `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Да, всё именно так. Я просто не понимаю, где я должен вызвать этот метод adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). В адаптере? В activity, где этот адаптер отображется? Хотя я думаю, что всё же в адаптере. А если в адаптере то где именно?.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged обновит весь список. Лучше делать обновление позиции через notifyItemChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас для редактирования айтема - отдельное активити (не фрагмент или диалогое окно в той же активти, что выводит список), в которой вы при внесении изменений вносите их в БД (или другое постоянное хранилище), на основе которого формируется список `RecyclerView` в другой активити.
 Тогда вам после внесения изменений в БД в активити редактирования айтема нужно просто вызвать активити, которая отображает список `RecyclerView`. Она будет создана заново и список заполнится с учетом внесенных в БД изменений, никаких дополнительных действий по нотификации адаптера или обработки колбэков не потребуется вовсе.

Так же стоит обнулить стек переходов активити (если активити с `RecyclerView` первое) или исключить активити редактирования айтема из стека переходов (если из активити со списком можно вернуться назад). Так как в противном случае при нажатии аппаратной кнопки "назад" вы вернетесь не в активити, которая вызвала активити со списком, как ожидается, а в активити редактирования айтема, что, как правило, не логично и не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сохранить позицию item для которого происходит редактирование. После того как отредактировали и вернули данные в оnActivityResult Вам нужно эти данные положить в список с данными, который Вы передали адаптеру. Нужно положить именно в ту позицию, которую вы сохранили при клике. И затем у адаптера вызвать notifyitemchanged